# Telephony/Communication (PBX) hardware for small company

Tags: voip, telephony

What is the best choice for communication system? I work in a company of 40 people and every one has a cordless-telephone and only a few of desktop phones we have a auto-responder to forward calls to the right extension.

We would like to switch our old analogic system to a IP-Voip system and I would like to find something with good software integration with other tools like MS Outlook/Exchange and Skype-for-Buiness.

I would like to switch all my DECT cordless to wifi devices so I can use only one type of antennas. Now I'm using Ubiquity Unifi antennas for wifi and I don't know if these are suitable for Voip-roaming.
I don't have a specific budget but considering the high number of cordless it is important to have a low-budget options for cordless.
We have some meeting room and I want to add some polycom devices specific for 
remote meeting, optionally with video connection (Skype?).

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for the software side of a PBX. If that's the case, we probably aren't the best place for advice. However, if you are looking for recommendations on what hardware your users should get, we can help. However, we'd need a few more details: Do you have specific features you want the phones to have (speed dial, video, etc)? Do you have a budget per phone?

Comment: Side note, on the software side: Look as [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/).

Comment: Thanks Andy, maybe I don't understand the narrow line between hw and sw in this case. If I have a voip connection to my provider should I use a PBX? Groups/users responders and so on do you consider this for sw or hw? I'm editing my question to add more details as requested.